# To to move to a new tab after selecting an option for a combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form which contains subforms organised by tabs. What I want to do is after updating a field while entering a new record, to redirect the user to a tab within the form.

This is may existing code.

```
Private Sub FIELD1_AfterUpdate()

If Me.FIELD1.Value = "Yes" Then

Me.Parent.TabCtl50.Value = 4

End If

End Sub
```

It gives the error "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the pages property:

```
 Me.Parent.TabCtl50.Pages(4).SetFocus
 Me.Parent.TabCtl50.Pages("PageNameHere").SetFocus
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it is giving the same issue, i think its causing that error because I'm trying to redirect the user to a different subfrom without saving the data first.....

Comment: No, not saving would not cause that error. The error is likely to be due to getting the name wrong in some way or another. For example, are you sure that me.parent has a TabCtl50? You can use the immediate window to test. Note that pages are numbered from zero.

Comment: You could try referring to the parent form by name, just to see if the issue is with `Me.Parent` such as `MyParentFormName.TabCtl50.Pages("PageNameHere").SetFocus`?

Comment: @SoupyC Yep, as long as the invalid name is not TabCtl50. For the most part, I think it is wise to find out why a problem is occurring rather than just working around. I tested the example, so it does work as long as the names are correct and the code is running in a subform of the form containing the tab control. It is not unusual for people to think they have a subform when all they have is the tabcontrol, in which case you would not need a reference to parent.

Comment: I figured out what it was, I had code in the AfterInsert event, which when I moved to the BeforeInsert event it solved all the problems. Thanks guys for all your help!